# Is there a way to tree shake out a function called in a class method?

Tags: javascript, esbuild, tree-shaking, terser

Let's consider this code :

```
class Foo {
   type;
   constructor(type) {
      this.type = type;
   }

   foo() {
     this.type === 'animation' ? create() : createNoop();
   }
}


new Foo('animation') 

function create() {
   console.log('create');
}
function createNoop() { 
   console.log('create Noop')
}
```

It there a way to refactor this, in order to get `createNoop()` tree shaken.

The key here is that `type` is meant to be readonly once it has been set by the constructor.

[Esbuild demo](https://esbuild.github.io/try/#YgAwLjE5LjMAewogIG1pbmlmeVN5bnRheDogdHJ1ZSwKICBidW5kbGU6IHRydWUsCn0AZQBlbnRyeS5qcwBjbGFzcyBGb28gewogICB0eXBlOwogICBjb25zdHJ1Y3Rvcih0eXBlKSB7CiAgICAgIHRoaXMudHlwZSA9IHR5cGU7CiAgIH0KCiAgIGZvbygpIHsKICAgICB0aGlzLnR5cGUgPT09ICdhbmltYXRpb24nID8gY3JlYXRlKCkgOiBjcmVhdGVOb29wKCk7CiAgIH0KfQoKCm5ldyBGb28oJ2FuaW1hdGlvbicpIAoKZnVuY3Rpb24gY3JlYXRlKCkgewogICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygnY3JlYXRlJyk7Cn0KZnVuY3Rpb24gY3JlYXRlTm9vcCgpIHsgCiAgIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCdjcmVhdGUgTm9vcCcpCn0) / [Terser REPL](https://try.terser.org/).

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: A code without the definition of `createNoop()`

Comment: I don't think any tree shaker can prove that `createNoop` isn't used unless using environment variables or packaging constants

Comment: How do you expect the transpilers to know the difference between `create` and `createNoop` when they seem identical?

Comment: @DanielA.White That's what I was afraid of.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The content doesn't matter to minifiers here.

Comment: Make `type` private? I.e. `#type`? That would help mark it as readonly...

Comment: The tree shaker would have to prove that you can never call `new Foo('not animation')`. How is it supposed to do that?

Comment: @Barmar  it not been exported should prove it.